# Minimize window in javafx2

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

i have undecorate the window in javafx2. Now i want to minimize the window by means of the action. This is my code

```
    minIcon.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
            primaryStage.toBack();
        }
    });
```

The window is go back when another one is open. otherwise its not. pls let me know how how to do this?

Answer (score 43):

After searching for some times i found answer myself.

```
minIcon.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
        primaryStage.setIconified(true);
    }
});
```

This works fine..

Comment: I don't get the solution... a little bit more context would be nice. I am using CSS. How can I implement this minimize action?

Comment: ÷1 for your answer, -1 to javafx devs for the less intuitive method name ever made

Comment: but how to get primaryStage?

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work:

```
iconid.setOnMouseClicked( event -> {
  Stage obj = (Stage) iconid.getScene().getWindow();
  obj.setIconified(true);
});
```

Edit: I'm new here so I didn't know to present my code better. So I'll try my best.

Here's the expln:-
Variable meanings-
`iconid`: The fxid of your ImageView element.
`obj`   : random stage object that you can declare.

The `event ->{}` is a lambda function and it reduces my work so I use it often.

What the second line does is it creates a new stage object and equates it to the current stage being shown, which is retrieved using `.getScene().getWindow()` property. I used the same ImageView element for consistency but you can use any element belonging to the same stage.(e.g. a button from the same window)

Third line is where you call the method `setIconified(boolean)` [Not the best naming ik, but I think it has to do with 'iconifying' it to the taskbar-turning it into an icon from a window] Setting it to 'true' minimizes your specified window.
That's about it.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to close the current stage is:

```
@FXML
public void onMinimize(){
    ((Stage) mainPage.getScene().getWindow()).setIconified(true);
}
```

This method is called when a button is pressed. The main focus of this answer is the code block within.

This is a very compact solution. First, we get the window from the main page. Then cast it to a stage. Then we use the `.setIconified(true)`. There is no animation, but it works.
The variable `mainPage` is [AnchorPain](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html). I think it would work with any type of pane. I defined it in the class as such:

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane mainPage;
```

Comment: make sure to get the spelling of the _technical_ terms correctly. btw: note that public methods don't need the fxml annotation